# Bootstrap v4.0 New method for offsetting columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

I just cannot make sense of Bootstrap v4.0's new way of offsetting columns. The documentation explains very little about it. I'm still used to being able to offset a column by a defined column value like `col-md-offset-2`. How would I do that in the new grid framework now?

I've tried several variations of `ml-auto`, `mr-auto`, etc. and nothing seems to do what I want it to do which is `col-md-offset-<n>`.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what exact layout you're trying to create? E.g. write it down with v3 markup and I/we try to answer with v4 solution.

Comment: I'm trying to get this: <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2"></div>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm trying to get this: `<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2"></div>`

In Bootstrap v4 you can achieve it by applying `col-md-10` for a width of 10 columns, and `ml-md-auto` to "skip" the space on the left (which is exactly a width of 2 columns as one row is 12 columns):

```css
.row {
    background: red;
}

.row > div {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 ml-md-auto">md-10 offset-2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Besides the mentioned documentation section [about offsetting](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns), maybe [flexbox utilites](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) are also helpful in some cases.

**UPDATE:** [Bootstrap 4 beta 2](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/10/19/bootstrap-4-beta-2/) brings back the [offset classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns), you can use them like:

```
<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2"></div>
```

Comment: I updated my post because Bootstrap 4 beta 2 has just been released and it brings back the offset classes.